# The meaning of : "no muscle"

Tags: word-meaning

I heard this word in an American movie and searched the meaning but didn't find what makes sense here.
This is about a woman who had stolen one million bucks from mafia, and the mafia takes her sister hostage and sends a message to her while they had sent her the picture of her sister :

> (the message)
> *Just sent you a picture, I want you to get the money and come down to the third floor. Come alone, **no muscle**, if you want your sister to live.*

Comment: *[hired] [**muscle***](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/muscle)
*- One or more persons who have been **paid to intimidate** someone else (typically into doing something that will benefit the hired muscle's "boss").* BrE equivalent: *Don't bring **the heavy mob***.

Comment: Someone stole a million bunks from the mafia? Would that be one million or two million beds then?

Comment: @gotube may I ask what "Would that be one million or two million beds then?" means exactly?

Comment: @user48 I'm making a joke about the typo "bunks" where I think you mean "bucks". A bunk is a type of bed that stacks one on top of the other. So my question was a philosophical one about whether one bunk bed actually means two beds or just one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Muscle" here means "strong assistants", or "tough guys".  It is casual.  It is an example of metonymy (which is very common way of forming new slang, since it is easy to guess the meaning)

The message is saying "don't come with any tough guys"